# GPU related issues in SDL game

Tags: android, opengl, sdl-2

We've been trying to get a port of mkxp to android. It uses SDL 2 and opengl es 2. The game works perfectly on Mali GPUs, but doesn't work as expected on PowerVR and is completely broken on Adreno. Is there any work around? Is it, for example, possible to completely bypass hardware acceleration and use software rendering, because some parts (eg the backgrounds etc.) work on all devices. I'm a beginner, so please don't mind any foolish question :)